# Stack Overflow & run code snippet?

Tags: discussion, design

I found a question which contains "run code snippet".

It is very nice to me. How can I run a code snippet into my Stack Overflow question?

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990460/my-html-footer-wont-move-downward).

[image]

Comment: There is a icon in the editor panel which looks like a document with script tags in it and says "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet Ctrl-M" in the tooltip.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

There's a button for this purpose.

[image]

Comment: Is it only for JS/CSS/HTML? Are there snippets for other languages?

Comment: it seems like yes. Only for those for now

Comment: @improbable now they have it also for scala, and most probably also for other languages.